# Regex match group based on array with key value

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is what I'm currently doing to match values in the `vars` array with object keys inside of `newaction`.

```
Object.keys(newaction).forEach((e) => {
        try {
            var newVal = newaction[e].replace(regex, (_match, group1) => vars[group1]);
            newaction[e] = newVal;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

So each matching property of `newaction` will be replaced by the value in `vars` which has a matching key.

What I'm trying to do now is replace the value in `newaction` with the matching value in vars, but where the value in vars is an array.

So say vars looks like this:

```
[{
    "name": "test",
    "value": ["HP": '35',
    "Atk": '55',
    "Def": '30',
    "SpA": '50',
    "SpD": '40',
    "Spe": '90',]
}]
```

If I now want to match it in the form of `newvalue[e]` being `test[HP]` to get the value '35', the original regex does not work.

Comment: You can't have key:value pairs in an array, only in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `vars` to an object whose key is the name and value is the object with the key:value pairs. Then you can use the two groups as indexes into the main object and nested object.

```js
vars = {
  "test": {
    "HP": '35',
    "Atk": '55',
    "Def": '30',
    "SpA": '50',
    "SpD": '40',
    "Spe": '90'
  }
};

const regex = /(\w+)\[(\w+)\]/;
Object.keys(newaction).forEach((e) => {
  try {
    var newVal = newaction[e].replace(regex, (_match, group1, group2) => vars[group1][group2]);
    newaction[e] = newVal;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to work, but it no longer is matching how it was previously in cases where there is only one group

Comment: Right, this only works for the new problem. You can use the old code for the original replacements.